# What are some good progressive web apps (PWA)?

Tags: apps, google, maps

I found out about progressive web apps (PWA), specifically for Google Maps from https://thenextweb.com/apps/2017/12/14/googles-lightweight-maps-go-is-just-a-progressive-web-app-heres-how-to-try-it/. I loaded it onto my idol 4S and wow! This is pretty much the Android app experience, and could really close the "app gap" on Windows Phone/Mobile.

So are there any other good PWAs out there? What I really would like to see are versions for Google Hangouts, Google Drive, and Google Voice. Or any other major app that is missing from our ecosystem.

And please, create a Start screen shortcut for the maps link. It is really good -- it even detected I was signed into Google!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of sites that list Progressive Web Apps

1. [Google Developers Showcase](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/tags/progressive-web-apps) - This site lists all case studies or showcases of PWAs in Google developer website.
2. [PWADirectory.AppSpot](https://pwa-directory.appspot.com/) - Website based on GitHub repo which lists PWAs(The frequently updated one I have seen so far).
3. [PWA.Rocks](https://pwa.rocks/) - Website based on GitHub repo which lists PWAs.
4. [Outweb.io](https://outweb.io/) - A webite where you can add new PWA you come across. This website itself is a PWA.
5. [PWA Stats](https://www.pwastats.com/) - A community-driven list of stats and news related to Progressive Web Apps.
6. [App Scope](https://appsco.pe/) - The best thing about this site is the neatly organized categories and simple looks. It is also free of ads.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few sites that list PWAs:

- https://pwa.rocks/
- https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/tags/progressive-web-apps
- https://pwa-directory.appspot.com/

Answer (score 4):

Another great resource is Appsco.pe (https://appsco.pe), a collection of the very best PWAs on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two great PWA websites. They both have a Lighthouse score of 100.

1. [Edgy](https://edgy.app/) (news)
2. [SEO.app](https://seo.app)